# SWIFT Removing Subviews

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer, subviews

I'm trying to have the ability to remove the subview the user chooses with three taps.
The problem I'm having is I can only get it to remove in the order the subviews were created. I have played around with 'viewWithTag' but can't figure out how to get it to do what I want.

Can I achieve what I want with the 'tapGesture' removing the subview from the location I tapped?

I'm a noob (as the kids say), so any help is much appreciated!
Thanks!

```
@IBAction func unwindToParent(segue:UIStoryboardSegue){
    var source = segue.sourceViewController  as PropViewController
    var propImage = UIImage(named: name as String!)
        clipView = UIImageView(image: propImage!)

        clipView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0, 200.0)
        clipView.center = CGPoint (x: view.bounds.size.width/2, y: view.bounds.size.height/2)
        clipView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
        clipView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        clipView.multipleTouchEnabled = true
        clipView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0



        setTag = tagCounter
        tagCounter++
        clipView.tag = setTag


        addPinchGestureRecognizer(clipView)
        addPanGestureRecognizer(clipView)
        addRotationGestureRecognizer(clipView)
        addTapGestureRecognizer(clipView)

        view.addSubview(clipView)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(clipView)

    let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("Trash:"))
        recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 3
        recognizer.delegate = self
        clipView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)

}


    func Trash(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){

         clipView.viewWithTag(setTag)?.removeFromSuperview()

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The gesture recogniser has a view property - that will be the tapped view.

Never use tags for anything.

Comment: Assuming there is one view and its the view you want. He could have a view, with no gesture, on top of the view with the gesture

Comment: The code in the question adds a gesture recogniser and tags to a view which is then removed when the gesture fires.

Answer (score 0):

Theres probably a half dozen ways I can see this being done.

The 'simplest' is probably getting the location of the tap

```
tap.locationInSubview
```

And then checking if any of the views contain that point

```
uiViewObject.containtsPoint()
```

If it contains the point remove it

Or you could add gestures to each view and, as suggested by jrturton, uses the taps view source as the view to remove.